# Extract specific strings from text file in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a text file that looks like this:

> text = {'symbol': 'TFUELUSDC', 'bidPrice': '0.00000000', 'bidQty':
>   '0.00000000', 'askPrice': '0.00000000', 'askQty': '0.00000000'},
>   {'symbol': 'TFUELTUSD', 'bidPrice': '0.00000000', 'bidQty':
>   '0.00000000', 'askPrice': '0.00000000', 'askQty': '0.00000000'},
>   {'symbol': 'TFUELPAX', 'bidPrice': '0.00000000', 'bidQty':
>   '0.00000000', 'askPrice': '0.00000000', 'askQty': '0.00000000'},
>   {'symbol': 'ONEBNB', 'bidPrice': '0.00020530', 'bidQty

I'd like to get an output where I only get the string that follows 'symbol'

Ideal output would look like

```
'TFUELUSDC', 'TFUELTUSD', 'TFUELPAX', 'ONEBNB'
```

I tried using different Regex methods such as:

```
> nameRegex = re.compile(r'symbol (.*) bidPrice (.*)') 

> nameRegex.search(text)
```

But I didnt not get any matches

I also tried :

```
> matching = [s for s in text if "USD" in s]
```

The reason I tried the above is there is only 10 different pairs for the names after symbol so they all finish with BTC, USDT, ETH etc...

This seems very simple but for some reason I am struggling way more than I would have thought.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You regex does not match the format of the input. What you want to extract is `'symbol': '*anything but quote*'`, so you need the word symbol in quotes, then colon, then possible space, then quotes, then anything but quotes, then quotes again. ANd you are interested in the thing between quotes

```
nameRegex = re.compile(r"'symbol':\s*'([^']+)')"
symbols=re.findall(nameRegex,text)
//because of the () it will return results as list of groups and not strings
symbol_strings = [g.group(1) for g in symbols]
```